# fisheriris data and perceptron

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

i want to apply the perceptron algorithm for fisheriris data and  i was tried this code

```
function [  ] = Per(  )
%PERCEPTON_NN Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
%%%%%%%%%%%STEP ONE INPUT DATA PREPERATION
%N=3000;
load fisheriris
tr=50; %traning
te=50; %test
epochs =150;

data=meas;
%N = size(meas,1);
%species=nonomil(species)
%figure,plot(data_shuffeled(1,:),data_shuffeled(2,:),'rx');
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%STEP TWO INTIALIZE  WEIGHT
baise=1;
w=[baise; 1 ; 1;1 ; 1];
eta=0.9; %%learning rate
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Rosen Blatt learning Algo
for epoch=1 : epochs 
for i=1 : tr
   x=[1;data(i,1);data(i,2);data(i,3);data(i,4)]; % input vector
   N = size(species,i); %desiard output
   y=w'*x; % y=actual output ,w'= transpose w , mmoken y=w.*x 
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Activation function (hardlimit)(step fn)
   y=1*(y>=0)+(-1)*(y<0); % da badl el if 
   %%%%%%%%%%% Error calcualtion %%%%%%%
   err(i)=N-y;
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%% update weight %%%%%%%%%5
   wnew=w+ eta*err(i)*x;
   w=wnew;
end
mse(epoch)=mean(err.^2);
end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  step four classification (testing) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5
hold on
for i=1 : te
    %x=[1;data(i,1);data(i,2),data(i,3);data(i,4)];
     x=[1;data(i,1);data(i,2);data(i,3);data(i,4)]; 
   % d=data_shuffeled(3,i+tr);
    N = size(species,i);
    y=w'*x;
    y=1*(y>=0)+(-1)*(y<0);
    if (y==1)
        plot(x(2),x(3),x(4),x(5),'rx');
    elseif y==-1
        plot(x(2),x(3),x(4),x(5),'r&');
    end
end
hold off

 if abs(N-y)>1E-6
    testerro=testerro+1;

end
```

i wrote this code to make the perceptron algorithm with fisheriris data "meas" as input and species as "output"

any help in the code or any modify on this code .

Thanks .

Comment: This question is too general. In the future, please provide manageably small code snippets that indicate a specific issue you are facing, and then indicate exactly what it is you are looking for- a performance improvement, an error your getting, things like that.

Answer (score 0):

First, did you know that MATLAB has something for neural network training called the [Neural network toolbox?](http://www.mathworks.com/products/neural-network/)

Second, think data_shuffeled is your own function. There is something called `randperm` in MATLAB that you should use to shuffle your data.

Third, you want to avoid using for-loops when you can use vectors/matrices in MATLAB.

Instead of doing (for testing)

```
for i = 1:te,
   ....
end
```

You might want to do

```
X = [ones(te,1), data]; %X is [50x5] so each row of X is x'
y = X*w;   %y is [50x1], X is [50x5], w is [5x1]
idx_p1 = y==1; %all the indices of y where y is +1
idx_m1 = y==-1; %all the indicies of y where y is -1

plot(X(idx_p1,1),y(idx_p1),'rx');
plot(X(idx_m1,1),y(idx_m1),'r&');
```

I don't know how you were using `plot` with 4-dimensional X so the above just plots with the first feature (column) of X.

Additionally, the training looks strange to me. For one, I don't think you should use N for both the size of data matrix meas and for the desired output. 'yhat' or 'ybar' is a better name. Also, if N is the desired output, then why is it `size(species,i)` where i loops through 1:50? species is a [150x1] vector. `size(species,1) = 150`. And `size(species,x)` where x is 2 to 50 will be 1. Are you sure you want this? Shouldn't it be something like:

```
yhat = -ones(50,1); %Everything is -1
yhat(strmatch('virginica,species)) = 1; %except virginicas which are +1
```

Comment: but i need to train the fisheriris data

Comment: How to do this with perceptron training algorithm

Comment: It's possible I've misunderstood your comments but here's a response to them (1) This isn't a replay of your question. It is an attempt to answer your very broad question with concrete ways to improve your code (2) This does specifically address your code and the fisheriris data. I wouldn't have put that part in there about strmatch('virginica,species)) if it wasn't. (3) Neural networks *are* single-layer perceptrons.